# How to delete a specific number in file?

Tags: linux, files, perl, sed

I have a file:

```
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
```

I want delete all zeros:

```
1 2 5 6 8 
1 2 5 6 8 
1 2 5 6 8 
1 2 5 6 8
```

I tried `tr -d [:0:]`. Unfortunately, it is not supposed to work in this way.

I believe `sed` and perl would do the job, but I do not know exactly how.

I searched on google, if you believe me, the results are mixed and relevant, but I am not able to find the right one in the first page.

Comment: Can you elaborate with a real example please? This looks suspiciously like a homework question, and those don't fit well with this site.

Comment: This is a real example from my Kaggle competition. https://www.kaggle.com/c/yelp-restaurant-photo-classification

Comment: I agree with your last point. I found Unix & Linux is better.

Comment: "I want to delete all zeroes" -- you mean all fields with value zero, right? If you have the number "100", you don't want to have just "1" as a result, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` is fine for this job:

```
tr -d 0 <file
```

`[:0:]` is invalid because you need to use a [character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) between `[:` and `:]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
[8]root@lab711:> cat file
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
1 2 5 6 8 0 0 0 0
[8]root@lab711:> sed 's/0//g' file
1 2 5 6 8
1 2 5 6 8
1 2 5 6 8
1 2 5 6 8
```

Comment: This is going to leave all the spaces between the `0`s in the output

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
perl -pe 's/\s+0\b//g' <filename>
```

- `-p` loops on files line and print `$_`
- `-e` execute
- `/g`Global (all occurences)
- Regex `s/\s+0\b//` is deleting series of at least one space, followed by character `0`, followed by end of word.

Or, in place replacement in file,

```
sed -ibbak -e 's/\s\+0\b//g' <filename>
```

- `-i` in place
- `-b.bak` make back-up (extention is `.bac`)
- Here the regex `+` character must be escaped.
- `\s` in regex is one space
- `\b` in regex is End of word

Hopes it makes a kick start!

Comment: wrong. That leaves you with `800` as the last field. You are too greedy with your whitespace, leaving yourself with two zeros with *no preceding whitespace*. You want `s/\s+0\b//g`

Comment: `Hokinaru:~$ echo '5 6 800' | sed 's/\s\+0\s\+//g'
5 6 800`  As expected...  But end of word is indeed a good idea.

Comment: Try using this input: `5 6 8 0 0 0 0`

Comment: indeed...  That makes the regex more complex, but that is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

In order to you remove all zero's in the file the command to use is `sed 's/0//g' filename` the `s` stands for substitute. The `/0` stands for all 0's in the file. the `//` stands for replace with nothing. The `g` stands for globally

Comment: It's important to note that the `/` character is actually just the delimiter, nothing special really. While hard to read, `sed 's1011g' filename` is just as valid.

Comment: oh wow I did not know that thanks for the info

Comment: @zak, funny example. How about `sed 's0\000g'`